# I can log in kaizala but fail to manage.kaiza.la and kaizala Management Portal

Tags: kaizala

I can log in kaizala but fail to manage.kaiza.la and kaizala Management Portal.
I want to send messages to Kaizala groups through Kaizala API, but fail to register a connector on step 1. please check the screenshot, anyone knows how to solve it? thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1KWB.png)